# Spring session redis issue on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-session

We are facing issue on spring session configuration with spring boot.

everything works fine on local but when we deploy on aws tomcat is providing memory leak error.
application start with "Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode" as we are using mysql as database and added redis-starter for spring session.

### I have also attached log from aws tomcat.

```
2017-03-08 16:26:08.556  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.service.repositories.InboundMessageRepository.
2017-03-08 16:26:08.556  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.service.repositories.RaffleRepository.
2017-03-08 16:26:09.108  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2017-03-08 16:26:09.480  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManage
mentConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$622093c3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2017-03-08 16:26:09.600  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3796 ms
2017-03-08 16:26:11.128  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.l.r.resource.DefaultClientResources    : ioThreadPoolSize is less than 3 (2), setting to: 3
2017-03-08 16:26:11.129  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.l.r.resource.DefaultClientResources    : computationThreadPoolSize is less than 3 (2), setting to: 3
2017-03-08 16:26:11.441  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.441  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.441  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Filter springSessionRepositoryFilter was not registered (possibly already registered?)
2017-03-08 16:26:11.441  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.441  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.443  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.444  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.447  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-03-08 16:26:11.449  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2017-03-08 16:26:13.863  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-08 16:26:13.895  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: default
        ...]
2017-03-08 16:26:14.076  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
2017-03-08 16:26:14.080  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-03-08 16:26:14.081  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-03-08 16:26:14.149  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-03-08 16:26:14.757  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2017-03-08 16:26:16.116  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator         : HHH000229: Running schema validator
2017-03-08 16:26:17.317  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-03-08 16:26:17.988  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

2017-08 16:26:23.074  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-03-08 16:26:24.016  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-03-08 16:26:24.029  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Starting beans in phase 2147483647
2017-03-08 16:26:24.241 ERROR 13318 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.d.r.l.RedisMessageListenerContainer  : Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms
2017-03-08 16:26:29.128  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.service.DataLoader               : Active Profile is : stage, Ignoring Data Loading...
2017-03-08 16:26:29.134  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : No TaskScheduler/ScheduledExecutorService bean found for scheduled processing
2017-03-08 16:26:29.160  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] c.service.SpringBootWebApplication   : Started SpringBootWebApplication in 24.47 seconds (JVM running for 31.608)
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.210 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.227 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/serviceWebApp] startup failed due to previous errors
2017-03-08 16:26:29.234  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@702c308: startup date [Wed Mar 08 16:26:05 UTC 2017]; root of context hier
archy
2017-03-08 16:26:29.240  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2017-03-08 16:26:29.244  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-03-08 16:26:29.286  INFO 13318 --- [ost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.325 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [serviceWebApp] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application w
as stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

as stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.327 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [serviceWebApp] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it
. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
 com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.328 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [serviceWebApp] appears to have started a thread named [threadDeathWatcher-4-1] but has failed to stop it. This is ver
y likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 io.netty.util.ThreadDeathWatcher$Watcher.run(ThreadDeathWatcher.java:147)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:145)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.334 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [serviceWebApp] appears to have started a thread named [globalEventExecutor-2-2] but has failed to stop it. This is ve
ry likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
 java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
 java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor.takeTask(GlobalEventExecutor.java:90)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor$TaskRunner.run(GlobalEventExecutor.java:233)
 io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:145)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.354 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/serviceWebApp.war has finished in 30,301 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.355 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.394 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 39 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.394 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.440 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/host-manager has finished in 44 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.440 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.455 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/docs has finished in 14 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.455 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/examples has finished in 196 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.651 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.670 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/tomcat/webapps/manager has finished in 19 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.682 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.692 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
08-Mar-2017 16:26:29.693 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 30720 ms
08-Mar-2017 16:26:44.163 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationContextEvent.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/context/event/ApplicationContextEvent.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)




08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.408 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitial
izer.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to at
tempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.411 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataS
ourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedInMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/devtools/autoconfigure/DevToolsDataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedInMemoryDatabaseShutdownExecutor.class]. The following
 stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.411 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/orm/jpa/vendor/Database.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.412 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties$Hibernate.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties$Hibernate.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.412 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties$Naming.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties$Naming.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.412 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/beans/PropertyMatches.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/beans/PropertyMatches.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.413 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/beans/PropertyMatches$BeanPropertyMatches.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/beans/PropertyMatches$BeanPropertyMatches.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.o.aA.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.sparktale.bugtale.agent.a.CU.a(Unknown Source)

08-Mar-2017 20:26:28.413 INFO [Takipi-INST] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedBindingNotWritablePropertyException.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org/springframework/boot/bind/RelaxedBindingNotWritablePropertyException.class]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1352)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1028)
```

Comment: could you provide more details on "redis-starter for spring session"? Perhaps you do not need to do that. The only thing you need to change when deploying to AWS is your redis endpoint URL, assuming you have provided configuration for creating redis-related spring beans like RedisTemplate, JedisConnectionFactory etc.

Comment: Hi Jayz, I am using "spring-boot-starter-data-redis" and "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" dependency I think with create warning message "[ost-startStop-1] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data Redis - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface". Currently I am using redis only for session and mysql as database. I have already configured JedisConenctionFactory. As all this setup work locally only issue while deploying on aws. Can you please help me what is issue?

Comment: you could remove "spring-boot-starter-data-redis" and simply add spring-session-data-redis as a maven dependency

Comment: ok Jayz let me try that

Comment: @Jayz that is not worked

Comment: Hi @HiteshR did you solve your issue? If so how? Since i am facing a similar issue